# Throwing an exception in performBackgroundTask closure

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4.2

There is a function, I'm storing data from a web response to my database, using Cora Data. The function should throw a `DataError` exception if some data is missing, or empty or null etc.
The database operations have to run on a background task with `privateQueueContext`. Before storing the data to the database, I check if it already exists (via `fetchRequest`). If the result is empty I start processing the data and storing it to the database.

I can throw an exception from outside the closure, but I'd like to throw an exception in the `performBackgroundTask` closure too, but I get a build error.

Here is the method:

```
private func processLittleItems(informationsFromWebServiceResponse : GetInformationsFromWebServiceResponse) throws {
    guard let littleItemListDataFromResponse = informationsFromWebServiceResponse.littleItemList else {
        throw DataError.dataMissing("littleItemList")
    }
    CoreDataStack.shared.persistentStoreContainer.performBackgroundTask { privateQueueContext in
        for littleItem in littleItemListDataFromResponse {
            let littleItemRequest = LittleItem.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<LittleItem>
            littleItemRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", littleItem.iD!)
            littleItemRequest.fetchLimit = 1

            do {
                let littleItemlist = try privateQueueContext.fetch(littleItemRequest)
                if (littleItemlist.isEmpty) {
                    let newLittleItem = LittleItem(context: privateQueueContext)
                    guard let littleItemId = littleItem.iD else {
                        return  // HERE SHOULD BE THROW EXCEPTION, NOT JUST A RETURN
                    }
                    newLittleItem.id = littleItemId

                    newLittleItem.optionalThing = littleItem.optionalThing ?? false
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        do {
            try privateQueueContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help with that?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunalty, it's not that easy.
If the caller of `processLittleItems` expects an exception (or a return value) from the function, it has to wait until everything is stored. Therefore, async processing will not work in this case.
So you have to rethink about how error handling will be done in your app:

- Either the caller of `processLittleItems` needs to wait, therefore you have to remove the background job and do everything synchronously
- Or the caller must not wait (because this would block the UI thread). In that case, the caller could provide a completion handler, which you would then from inside your background closure and hand in the error/success code.

Comment: Many thanks, than I have to thinking around this function!

Answer (score 1):

Andreas Oetjen is right about it. you throw basically exceptions for sync methods not async methods.

One options is define you own completion handler or callback depending upon you logic and use it to send error back and use it when required. 
sample:

`private func processLittleItems(informationsFromWebServiceResponse : GetInformationsFromWebServiceResponse, completion: (_ error: Error?, object: Any?) -> Void)`

and when exception occurs.
`completion('your exception', nil)`

hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks, than I have to thinking around this function!